# How can a team download server code from a Mobile App service on Azure Portal

Tags: visual-studio, azure, mobile, azure-web-app-service

We have a mobile app service on Azure Portal.

We are a team with 3 members.

We hope to contribute to the server code (C#) together.

How can other teammates download the code which is published by one of us?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could get the published files from azure WebApp with Azure kudu tool(https://www.sitename.scm.azurewebsites.net/), but the files **are compiled**, not the source code.

In your case, your team members could push your code to source control server such as **[github](https://github.com/)**, **[VSTS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/)**,etc. Then team members could work together. And Azure WebApp(Mobile App) Allows us to [continuous Deployment to Azure App Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-continuous-deployment). We could config Deployment options in azure portal.

> In your app's menu blade in the Azure portal, click APP DEPLOYMENT > Deployment options. Click Choose Source, then select the deployment source.

[image]

Comment: Yeah. It seems we can only get the binary of compilation.